# Chained Select Boxes with Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have two select boxes on a page that I am using Chained plugin to manage. The first select box identifies a type of report to be produced (and can be hard coded) that links to a second select box requiring dynamic arrays fetched from a database.

I have both select boxes working and one array setup in the second select box relating to funds, as you will see below. The issue I am having now is trying to implement another dynamic array for commissions. I'll note here, the select boxes are not limited to two report options - I'm just starting with two simple queries to get things working then I'll build on it.

```
$queries = "SELECT DISTINCT(ProductName) FROM dbFund ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
$datas = mysql_query($queries);

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="reportType" id="reportType">
        <option value="">----Select Report----</option>
        <option value="funds">Funds</option>
        <option value="commission">Commissions</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="reports" id="reports" onChange="reportsSelect(this)">
        <?php 
            while($fetch_options=mysql_fetch_array($datas)) { 
        ?>
        <option class="funds" id="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?>">
            <?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have some additional script which links 'reports' to 'reportType' and sends off both select box values to a php file to produce an output table that is working fine for 'funds'. I need help with adding option class="commission" that will be a similar query from a database table.

If I've gone about this the wrong way I'd appreciate some pointers on what I should be using instead.

**EDIT - [Chained Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)**

```
            <script>

            $(function() {
                $("#reports").chainedTo("#reportType");
            });

            function reportsSelect(str) {
                alert(str.options[str.selectedIndex].value);

                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("reportHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("reportHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    var str = document.getElementById("reports").value;                     
                    var stl = document.getElementById("reportType").value;
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","process/getReport.php?q="+str+"&z="+stl,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Please show what Chained plugin do you use and javascript function about `reportType()` and `reportsSelect()`.

Comment: Added - also there is no reportType() function that was prior to adding the Chained plugin (I've removed it).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a column in datatable names class, so you can add this to your `mysql_fetch_array` loop like below:

```
<select class="form-control" name="reports" id="reports" onChange="reportsSelect(this)">
    <?php 
        while($fetch_options=mysql_fetch_array($datas)) { 
    ?>
    <option class="<?php echo $fetch_options['class']; ?>" id="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?>">
        <?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And in reportType function, use `xmlhttp.responseText` in the end to do whatever you want.

I don't know whether I figure your problem or not. If I am wrong somewhere, please tell me.

Comment: I'm lost on your answer...the Chained plugin uses the option class to link to the 'reportType' option value, its already using javascript to link them. I need a method of pulling in another array when a different reportType is selected, using a completely different query as well. I assumed this was possible using only PHP.